# The MySQL syntax that is not run always fails on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, putty

I am a linux beginner, especially ubuntu. I want to manage the mysql database installed on my Ubuntu web server by using Putty. But the MySQL syntax that I run always fails. Example syntax:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

All failed messages are the same for any syntax:

> mysql: unknown variable 'bind-address = 0.0.0.0'

I don't know whether to run the Mysql syntax on Ubuntu I need to go to a certain Folder/Path, like in windows if I want to run the mysql syntax I need to go to the path where MySql is installed, for example `C:/xampp/mysql/bin` and then run the syntax `mysql -u root -p`.

is there anything I miss? and what should i do? please help, thank you.

Comment: In your **my.cnf** file, the variable should be `bind_address`, not `bind address`.

Comment: I fixed the post

Comment: bind-address is still wrong. It is bind_address.

Comment: @Jeremy Hariss Variables in my my.cnf file is bind-address not bind_address. Should it be bind_address?

Comment: Oh no, `bind-address` is right, my bad. The point is it's not valid with a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Option 1: A typo in a title**

Have a look in your my.cnf file. 
Maybe you have a typo: There should be [mysqld] instead of [mysql] section

```
 [mysqld] bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

OR

```
[mysqld] 
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

[Source](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000152345-Unable-to-update-Plesk-usr-bin-mysql-unknown-variable-bind-address-127-0-0-1-)

---

### **Option 2: Is it Maria DB?**

Are you sure you are using `MySQL` ?

This looks like a MariaDB error.

Try to remove the `bind-address` from your `mysql.cnf` file.

---

### **Option 3: Check for any whites-pace?**

Try editing the file and using `show all characters` in your editor (e.g. Notepad Plus Plus). Maybe there are whitespace characters ( such as spaces ) causing problems.

Comment: thank your for your respons. You're right, thank you for your help.

Comment: What was it ? I am curious !

Comment: Your answer to Option 1